# Skipping chunk of a big file with bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Using bash, how to awk/grep from the middle of a given file and skip 1Gig for instance?  In other words, I don't want awk/grep to search through the first 1Gig of the file but want to start my search in the middle of the file.

Comment: If performance is of concern, your best bet is to break up the large file into multiple smaller ones first.

Comment: I'd use perl, python or another language that lets you seek around in open files, instead of trying to use shell.

Comment: @Shawn you can use `dd` to seek in files.

Comment: Did I stutter or something?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dd` like this:

```
# make a 10GB file of zeroes
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G count=10 > file

# read it, skipping first 9GB and count what you get
dd if=file bs=1G skip=9 | wc -c
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 1.84402 s, 582 MB/s
1073741824
```

Note that I am just demonstrating a concept of how easily you can skip 9GB. In practice, you may prefer to use a 100MB memory buffer and skip 90 of them, rather than allocating a whole GB. So, in practice, you might prefer:

```
dd if=file bs=100M skip=90 | wc -c
```

Note also that I am piping to `wc` rather than `awk` because my test data is not line oriented - it is just zeros.

Or, if your record size is 30kB and you want to skip a million records and discard diagnostic output:

```
dd if=file bs=30K skip=1000000 2> /dev/null | awk ...
```

Note that:

- your line numbers will be *"wrong"* in `awk` (because `awk` didn't *"see"* them), and
- your first line may be incomplete (because `dd` isn't *"line oriented"*)  but I guess that doesn't matter.

Note also, that it is generally very advantageous to use a **large** block size. So, if you want 8MB, you will do much better with `bs=1m count=8` than with `bs=8 count=1000000` which will cause a million writes of 8 bytes each.

---

Note also, that if you like processing very large files, you can get **GNU Parallel** to divide them up for processing in parallel by multiple subprocesses. So, for example, the following code takes the 10GB file we made at the start and starts 10 parallel jobs counting the bytes in each 1GB chunk:

```
parallel -a file --recend "" --pipepart --block 1G wc -c
```

Comment: This will perform much better than any solution relying on counting lines (sed, awk, tail) for skipping, but is of course less "exact". The TS needs to modify for the approximate numbers for his application

Comment: Nice solution. I wouldn't use a `1GB` block size though, as it will end-up in RAM; the best size depends on the physical disks and the input buffer of the piped command

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, agreed. Some discretion should be used when choosing a block size.

Comment: This method is extremely powerful and can be expended to do binary searches in large sorted files.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested the performance on very large files, compared to `tail | grep`, but you could try GNU `sed`:

```sh
sed -n '3000001,$ {/your regex/p}' file
```

skips the first 3 millions lines and then prints all lines matching the `your regex` regular expression. Same with `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR>3000000 && /your regex/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the full size of the file (lets say 5 million lines) you can do this:

```
tail -2000000 filename|grep "yourfilter"
```

This way you will do whatever editing, or printing, starting below the first 3 million lines

Comment: Note that `cat <file> | tail -X` is the same thing as `tail -X <file>`, saving a pipe and (in this case) **lots** of memory.